# Unable to run android module

Tags: android, git, android-gradle-plugin, git-pull

My friend and I are working on an android project. he decided to include a module on the project and when he was done, he pushed it to our github account under a new branch.

when i git pulled the branch, **i can't run the module while he can run it on his computer.** the module **doesn't** appear darker and bold like other modules. here's the screenshot. module name is **army**

[image: android module]

here's the module's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xyz.abc"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}
```

what do i need to change so that i can be able to run the module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the module on **settings.gradle** file.

for example:

include ':app',':army'

Comment: this is the solution :)